# Creating own iOS-controls with Flex

Tags: ios, apache-flex, ipad

I was looking into creating iOS-apps (especially for the iPad) with the Adobe-Flex framework. It looks very promising to code apps this way.

Is it possible to create own controls/widgets? In the far future I might want to create my own kind of gantt-calender or whatever. Is something like this possible and are there any good tutorials/book out there?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** I want to create iOS Components that I can use in Flex. Controls, that are not aviable by default in Flex. Is that possible? By derivating or something?

**UPDATE 2:** In the meanwhile I found [FlexLib](https://code.google.com/p/flexlib) to be useful. How hard is it to create stuff like this on your own? Especially for mobile devices. Are there any good tutorials, books, etc. out there?

Comment: I'm unclear if you're looking to create Flex Components which look like iOS counterparts or if you're looking to create iOS Components that you can use in Flex.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com please look at my update.

Comment: @Flextras He wants flex components that look like the native iOS ones.

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu No, I don't want components that look like the native ones. I need owner drawn controls like in https://code.google.com/p/flexlib. My Question is in the meanwhile more like "how to do this" instead of is it possible.

Comment: @chiffre the flexlib are custom made controls. I am totally in blur right now. Am I and Flextras stupid or you just cannot explain what you want. Try with an sample of what you have in iOS and what you want in flex!

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu: You are not stupid, you're just guessing wrong ;) What I want to do is creating custom made controls. Those need to be run on an iPad, but don't need to look like native iOS-Controls. My Question is: How to achieve this and are there any good docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create your own Controls in Flex.  They are commonly called Components.  I suggest you start by reading the [Flex Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS4bebcd66a74275c35bf45738120d4f86190-8000.html) on how to do so.  There are also plenty of other resources out there.  One is a [screencast series](http://www.theflexshow.com/blog/index.cfm/Fifteen-Minutes-With-Flex) that I created for The Flex Show.  Here is [episode 1](http://www.theflexshow.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/3/2/The-Flex-Show--Creating-Flex-Components--Episode-1-Project-Setup).

You had asked:

> How hard is it to create stuff like this on your own?

It depends on what the component wants to do.  The commercial components we've built at [www.flextras.com](http://www.flextras.com) have taken from three to twelve months to build.  Our Calendar is built from scratch, but most of the other components extend existing Flex Framework components.

The Flextras stuff are architected for reuse.  A "single use" component for a specific app can be built in 1 hour [and up].

Once again, the purpose of a component will affect how long it takes to build.

Answer (score 1):

@chiffre

Ok, maybe I am guessing wrong but "iOS controls" makes me think not to "flex controls".

Anyway with Flex 4.5.1 you can add any controls you want, the only thing that you must count (and this counts a lot) is performance.

Read especially about item renderers since scrolling list is not so fast on iOS and how you can make use of cacheAsBitmap. 
Also keep in mind to always use light controls when needed if not extend base controls like UIComponent or Sprite and not Button if you just need a rectangle.

Here are some links 
http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2011/06/adobe-air-2-7-now-available-ios-apps-4x-faster.html
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/mobile-development-flex-flashbuilder.